# How to remove three consecutive line feeds in a Makefile rule?

Tags: centos, sed, perl, make, control-characters

I need to search for and replace three consecutive newline characters in an input file and filter them out of an output file for a makefile rule on Centos 4.  I am using GNU sed v4.1.2 and GNU make v3.82.  I've tried variations on the following with no success thus far:

```
THREE_LINE_FEEDS := $(shell echo "\012\012\012")

SED_RULE := 's/'$(THREE_LINE_FEEDS)'//'

output.txt: input.txt
    sed -r $(SED_RULE) input.txt > output.txt
```

Using the proposed perl, I get this issue in the shell (adapted from my make rule):

```
> cat input.txt | perl -e '$/ = undef; _ = <>; s/\n{3}//g; print;' > output.txt
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "<>;"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, here is the actual makefile rule (I couldn't get the newlines to work in the original, so used a comment to add the documentation):

```
# 0777  -  Enables slurp mode (i.e. $/ = undef;  -  Slurp mode, read whole file
#                                   $_ = <>;     -  Read file to $_)
# s/\n{3}//g;                                    -  Remove occurrences of \n{3}
# p     -  Implicitly print result (i.e. print;  -  Output $_)
output.txt: input.txt
    $(SED) -r $(SED_RULE) input.txt | perl -0777 -pe 's/\n{3}//g' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` only sees one line at a time, so searching for consecutive line-feeds will not work. One way is to push all the data into the hold space, and then do the replace when all input has been gathered, e.g.:

```
sed -r -n '
  $! {             # When it is not the last line
    1  { h }       # Replace hold space with first line
    1! { H }       # Otherwise append to hold space
  }
  $  {             # When last line reached
    H              # Append it to hold space
    g              # Replace pattern space with hold space
    s/\n{3}//g     # Remove all occurrences of \n{3}
    p              # Print pattern space
  }
' input.txt
```

Here is a simpler option using `perl`, but works in the same manner:

```
perl -e '
  $/ = undef;      # Slurp mode, read whole file
  $_ = <>;         # Read file to $_
  s/\n{3}//g;      # Remove all occurrences of \n{3}
  print;           # Output $_
' input.txt
```

#### Edit

A shorter `perl` version suggested by Peter O.:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n{3}//g' input.txt
```

- `-0777` enables slurp mode.
- `-p` implicitly prints result.

Comment: The perl is not working when inserted into my makefile rules, please see above updated question.

Comment: When using `$` in makefiles they need to be protected, i.e. add an extra `$` on there, so `perl -e '$$/ = undef; $$_ = <>; s/\n{3}//g; print' input.txt > output.txt` should work.

Comment: Yes, had figured that out, but still not working. Getting error: Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "<>;"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.  Can you pipe into perl?  Why is it executing -e?

Comment: The error you're getting comes from this bit: `_ = <>;`, should be `$_ = <>;`. Either of `perl -e ... infile` and `cat infile | perl -e ...` works. `-e` specifies the command `perl` should run, see `perlrun(1)`.

Comment: Bingo, it works now, needed other $ doubled in the makefile.

Comment: `perl -0777pe 's/\n{3}//g'` is exactly the same. `0777` puts Perl into file-slurp mode, and `p` makes a read loop which prints

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the `-0777` option.